# How to set array into float32 data type (need to be compatible with append)?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I ran into a problem with the float 32 for arrays. Basically, I have defined a function and I want to produce a series of results in array forms, called "Apoints" in the following code. So I found that if I use array([],numpy.float32), then with append commands, it will say 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append' .

Does anyone know what to do? Many thanks!

### Here is the code, and Apoints result in 64 bits, not 32.

```
def f(N):
        S = np.float32(0)
        for n in arange(1,N+1,1,dtype=np.float32):  #for upward summation
            #print S
            S = np.float32(np.float32(S) + np.float32(np.float32(1.0)/(np.float32((np.float32(n)*np.float32(n))))))
        return np.float32(np.float32(abs(np.float32((np.float32(S)-np.float32(R)))))/np.float32(R))


Npoints = []
Apoints = []
hpoints = []

Npoints = arange(10,1000,20,dtype=np.float32) 
for N in Npoints:
    Apoints.append(np.float32(f(N)))
    hpoints.append(np.float32(np.float32(1.0)/(np.float32(N))))

print Apoints
```

Comment: The repeated use of `np.float32()` looks odd.  What's it supposed to accomplish?  Appending to Python lists is common; it is not normal for numpy arrays.  There is a `np.append` function, but it is just a cover for `concatenate`.

Comment: Well, the obecjective is to creat an array or a list with 32 bit, so I used a lot of np.float32 to ensure the output Apoints will be in the correct format, which failed. I will try the np.append to see if it works. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Normally `np.float'32` is used as `dtype` for a whole array.

Answer (score 0):

*'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'*

-> You are trying to call append() on a numpy array but the type ndarray has no append method.
The explanation for this is simple: Arrays are immutable, so it does not make much sense to have some appending stuff on an numpy ndarray object.

Appending to arrays is a functionality provided directly in numpy. This creates a new array with all values (old and appended ones).

```
a = numpy.array( [1,2,3] )
b = numpy.array( [4,5,6] )
c = numpy.append(a,b)
print c
```

This generates the following output:

```
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

Numpy.append(a,b) creates a new array of a dimension equal to the dimension of a plus the dimension of b, so that the new array can hold the values of a **and** b. This new array is return, so you can save it as **c**.

For further explanations lookup the numpy documentation or start new questions ;)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so it is possible to create a dynamic array(not fixed in dimension) with float 32 bits?

Comment: Nope. That's not what I've said. Concerning its size arrays are immutable. You can never change the size of an array but you can use, for example, numpy.append(a,b) to get a new array c which contains the values of b appended to a. I've edited my answer a bit, I hope this is clear now.